# How to load properties from XML file with C#

Tags: c#, xml

I've a method which create an XML file

```
    public void saveXmlButtons()
    {

        XElement buttons = new XElement("Buttons"); // Create a root node
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            XElement id = new XElement("Button", listButtons[i].id.ToString());
            XElement type = new XElement("appType", listButtons[i].type);
            XElement isActive = new XElement("isActive", listButtons[i].isActive);
            XElement name = new XElement("name", listButtons[i].lblName.Content);
            XElement pathIcon = new XElement("pathIcon", listButtons[i].pathIcon);
            XElement pathApp = new XElement("pathApp", listButtons[i].pathApp);
            XElement button = new XElement("Button");
            button.Add(id);
            button.Add(type);
            button.Add(isActive);
            button.Add(name);
            button.Add(pathIcon);
            button.Add(pathApp);
            buttons.Add(button);
        }
        buttons.Save(@"btemp");
        loadXmlButton();

    }
```

Output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Buttons>
  <Button>
    <Button>0</Button>
    <appType>None</appType>
    <isActive>false</isActive>
    <name />
    <pathIcon>Resources/add.png</pathIcon>
    <pathApp />
  </Button>
  <Button>
    <Button>1</Button>
    <appType>None</appType>
    <isActive>false</isActive>
    <name />
    <pathIcon>Resources/add.png</pathIcon>
    <pathApp />
  </Button>
etc...
</Buttons>
```

I'm trying to read the different property of each node (Button, appType, isActile), and the documentation doesn't help me..
What is the best way to load each property ? This code doesn't works..

```
    public void loadXmlButton()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("btemp");
        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
        {

                string s = node.Attributes["pathApp"]?.InnerText;
                Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you writing Elements but reading Attributes?

Comment: I'd also strongly advise you to use LINQ to XML when reading, just like you did when writing. It's a much better XML API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, you'd be far better off using the same LINQ to XML API to read your XML as you did to write it. In addition, `pathApp` is an *element*, not an *attribute*, so you're currently using the old API incorrectly.

Try something like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("btemp");

foreach (var button in doc.Root.Elements())
{
    var id = (int)button.Element("Button");
    var type = (string)button.Element("appType");
    var isActive = (bool)button.Element("isActive");
    ...
}
```